# Is Azure SQL Database a Distributed SQL database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, distributed-system, cockroachdb

I am trying to understand the differences between the new CockroackDB and other distributed SQL databases as compared to a cloud-managed database like Azure SQL Database.

It seems there is no difference in the use cases between them:

1. Like various NOSQL databases SQL (in general) allows partitioning keys.
2. I can add cores in Azure to increase the performance as needed, I can also switch to Hyper-scale if I have an elastic workload.
3. I can have read replication across multiple nodes over multiple availability zones (geo-locations)
4. I can configure data replication in Azure SQL Database too.

It seems to me that a cloud SQL database covers all the use cases the newer distributed databases cover, so why would I want to use a newer product ?

**Isn't Azure SQL Database basically a distributed database server ?**

Am I missing something ?

Comment: do you mean "Azure SQL Database"?! SQL Server is something else entirely

Comment: @silent Correct I meant that hence my title contains Azure SQL Sever and not SQL Server.

Comment: no but then your title should be Azure SQL Database, thats my point ;)

Comment: @silent To say Azure SQL is "something else entirely" doesn't sit right with me... Azure SQL presents itself as being _almost like_ an on-prem SQL Server instance, and is functionally identical w.r.t. engine-features. I know there's some crazy stuff going on behind-the-scenes though...

Comment: I just want to be precise here. There is "Azure SQL Database" and there is "(Microsoft) SQL Server" (and there is Azure SQL Managed Instance). All three things are different.

Comment: @silent I hope the edits make it a little bit clearer.

Comment: Not really. You haven't said if you are asking about Azure SQL Database or an Azure SQL Managed instance (or perhaps even Azure Synapse).

Comment: @Larnu how about now ? I am asking about Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Azure SQL Server a Distributed SQL database?

No.

> Like various NOSQL databases SQL (in general) allows partitioning keys.

- Partitioning in NoSQL databases like Cassandra (and *Azure Table Storage*) is about distributing partitions to physically distinct *nodes*, and requires rows to have an explicitly set partition-key value.

  - Cassandra nodes are physically different machines that can run independently, which gives it excellent resiliency.
- Partitioning in *SQL Server*, *Azure SQL*, and *Azure SQL Managed Instance* is about dividing data up into row-groups that exist in the same server for performance, not resiliency.

  - On on-prem MS SQL Server, these row-groups (well, *partitions*) can exist in different `FILEGROUP`s, which means they can exist in different storage volumes to avoid IO bottlenecks, but Azure SQL does not support multiple `FILEGROUP`s.

    - [The benefits of implementing partitioning, including on Azure SQL, are documented online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes) - and the article explains how it's about performance, not resilience.

> I can add cores in Azure to increase the performance as needed, I can also switch to Hyper-scale if I have an elastic workload.

This fact has absolutely nothing to do with distributed databases.

> I can have read replication across multiple nodes over multiple availability zones (geo-locations).
> I can configure data replication in Azure SQL Database too.

- Replication isn't the same thing as a true distributed database:

  - In Cassandra and other distributed databases, all clients can connect to all nodes and accomplish the same tasks; and you can arbitrarily add and remove nodes while the system is running.
  - In SQL Server and Azure SQL's replication feature, the replica is strictly a "secondary" that is subordinate to your *primary* server.

    - Clients can connect to either the secondary or the primary, but the secondary server can only perform read-only queries, whereas if a client wants to do DML (`INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE`) or DDL (`CREATE/ALTER`) then the client must connect to the primary server.

> It seems to me that a cloud SQL database covers all the use cases the newer distributed databases cover, so why would I want to use a newer product?

It can't: because Azure SQL is not a distributed database it cannot allow any client to read *and write* to **any** node or endpoint and have that change replicated to all other nodes (using an *eventual consistency* model). Instead, Azure SQL requires writes to be performed by the single primary "server".

Note that an [Azure SQL "server" or *logical server*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logical-servers?view=azuresql) is largely an abstraction that hides what Azure SQL *really is*: a distinct build of SQL Server's engine that runs in a high-availability Azure Service Fabric environment (which is how cores/RAM can be added and removed while it's running and provides for some kind of local resilience against hardware failure) in a single Azure datacenter.

Comment: I think most of your points are correct, but not quite in some detail. Azure SQL is running on Service Fabric, so in fact it is not just a single physical server. That part is abstracted from the user and you are right, it does not behave like a NoSQL DB where you can connect to any instance. But it is still very different than a SQL Server which is physically one node and you need replication to build HA. Azure SQL has HA (even across AZs) built-in in that sense

Comment: @Dai So its still single point of failure because of the primary WRITE server ?

Comment: @silent Thanks - I've improved my answer.